# How to set time on android analog clock component?

Tags: android, clock

i was trying to write an analog world clock app. i wanted to use the analog clock component

```
<AnalogClock android:id="@+id/MyAnalogClock" />
```

This shows the system time. But how do we set a different time(say, a second clock showing time for a different country) to the analog clock component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot (I checked the source code).

But as Android is open source, you are invited to add the function.

The Widget is referring to the phones timezone only.

Comment: what would be the best approach to create an analog world clock in that case?

Comment: Probably subclass or copy & paste the existing one into a new class and add the missing functions.