# How do I set the time on an android analogue clock?

Tags: java, android, clock

I'm creating an android application that gets the current time in a different country/time-zone. I'm making it as there aren't many other apps on the marketplace that do the same job.

I've got an analogue clock with a digital clock underneath on my app, how do I change the time on the clocks - take on or off a number of hours? For example, I may want the clock to display the time in Florida, so for me that'd be -6 hours.

Although I'm proficient in other programming languages; mainly .NET I'm new to Java, so please excuse the simple questions!

Thankyou!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The analog clock widget in android [doesn't allow setting the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291923/how-to-set-time-on-android-analog-clock-component) but [you could adapt it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016368/android-programming-drawing-analog-clock) as the source is available.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to `android.widget.AnalogClock` and `android.widget.DigitalClock`, they only show the current device time. They are not designed for showing arbitrary times, as you seek.

Comment: Ok, does that mean that I'll have to create my own clock view?

That shouldn't be too much of a problem, I don't think.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Todd Davies: As @Colin Pickard suggested, you may be able to handle this via a subclass (doubtful) or a clone of the existing widgets (possible). However, if you don't like the look and feel of the existing one, you may as well roll something new from scratch.

Comment: Ok, I saw an article describing how to make a custom clock widget, I'll have several .png files and rotate them around a central point to form a clock. I'll also use a TextView to display a digital time underneath. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Todd Davies: can you please tell me where did  you find that article?

Comment: I can't remember, probably just a google search. It was quite a while ago. Sorry!