# Android programming - drawing analog clock

Tags: android, time

I am a novice at Android programming. How can I make a program that will draw an analog clock such that it can show time for various timezones as the user selects?

I had already Googled for the last few hours, but didn't find any particular solution to this problem. What I got completely puzzled me out. Please help me.

Comment: Isn't there already an application doing this?

Comment: can u pls suggest me something Nick that I can make my desired application? I could not find any such application. As i am learning Android development i want to make an application myself that will do like " the user will select the timezone, based on that the current time of that timezone will be set on the analog clock.."

Comment: Downvoted because this is question of type 'I need a program, send me teh source'.

Answer (score 15):

Hi Friends I have did the solution to my problem......
I wish to share the solution with u guys...

```
public class TimeShow extends Activity implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener{
Context context;
TextView tv;
RadioButton rb1,rb2,rb3;
RadioGroup r1;
FrameLayout fl1;
LinearLayout l1;
Timer timer;
Date result;
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp1;
Drawable bck;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    context=this;
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    r1=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup01);
    rb1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.RadioButton01);
    rb2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.RadioButton02);
    rb3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.RadioButton03);
    fl1=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.FrameLayout01);
    bck=this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.clockface);
    fl1.setBackgroundDrawable(bck);
    lp1=fl1.getLayoutParams();
    r1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    result=null;
}
```

Next is a method called updateTime as follows:

```
private void updateTime(String str) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       if(timer!=null)
       {
           timer.cancel();
           timer=null;
       }
       timer = new Timer();
       MyTime mt=new MyTime(this,str);
       timer.schedule(mt, 1, 1000);
    }

public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(rb1.isChecked() == true)
            updateTime("Asia/Kolkata");
        if(rb2.isChecked() == true)
            updateTime("Etc/GMT-6");
        if(rb3.isChecked() == true)
            updateTime("Asia/Karachi");
    }
    public class MyTime extends TimerTask {
        String tz;
        public MyTime(Context context,String str) {
            tz=str;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
                Date date=new Date();
                date=getDateInTimeZone(date, tz);
                //System.out.println(date.toLocaleString());
                result=date;
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        private Date getDateInTimeZone(Date currentDate, String timeZoneId) {
            TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneId);
            Calendar mbCal = new GregorianCalendar(tz);
            mbCal.setTimeInMillis(currentDate.getTime());
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, mbCal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, mbCal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mbCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mbCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mbCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, mbCal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
            cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, mbCal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));


            return cal.getTime();
        }
    }
    Handler handler=new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            tv.setText(result.toLocaleString());
            //System.out.println(result.getHours()+" "+result.getMinutes());
            fl1.removeAllViews();
            fl1.addView(new CustomClock(context, lp1.height/2, lp1.width/2, result));
        }
    };
}
```

And a class CustomClock that extends view:

```
public class CustomClock extends View {
    private final float x;
    private final float y;
    private final int r=45;
    private final Date date;
    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    public CustomClock(Context context, float x, float y, Date date) {
        super(context);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.date=date;        
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        //canvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, mPaint);
        float sec=(float)date.getSeconds();
        float min=(float)date.getMinutes();
        float hour=(float)date.getHours()+min/60.0f;
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        canvas.drawLine(x, y, (float)(x+(r-15)*Math.cos(Math.toRadians((hour / 12.0f * 360.0f)-90f))), (float)(y+(r-10)*Math.sin(Math.toRadians((hour / 12.0f * 360.0f)-90f))), mPaint);
        canvas.save();
        mPaint.setColor(0xFF0000FF);
        canvas.drawLine(x, y, (float)(x+r*Math.cos(Math.toRadians((min / 60.0f * 360.0f)-90f))), (float)(y+r*Math.sin(Math.toRadians((min / 60.0f * 360.0f)-90f))), mPaint);
        canvas.save();
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFA2BC13);
        canvas.drawLine(x, y, (float)(x+(r+10)*Math.cos(Math.toRadians((sec / 60.0f * 360.0f)-90f))), (float)(y+(r+15)*Math.sin(Math.toRadians((sec / 60.0f * 360.0f)-90f))), mPaint);
    }
}
```

Thanks All of my Friends for your kind help and suggestions....

Comment: do you have the source code of the customised analog clock. I tried your solution but I am unable to display the clock. Could you please share the link of the source code.

Answer (score 2):

Souvik,

You can start with "AnalagClock" control available in the Android system, drag and drop the AnalogClock control on screen or write a new tag manuaaly in main.xml.

Comment: Yes Sid thats true, but i want to make a program in which the user will select the timezone, based on that the current time of that timezone will be set on the analog clock.....