# make Analogclock in android

Tags: android, canvas, view, time, clock

I'm new to android and I want to make a simple app in which I want display analog clock. I know how clock works but I not able to design it. till now I have drawn the circle and now I want to attach the resources but  I don't know how to do it. can anyone please help me out and give me the procedure. thank you

```
public class MyView extends View
{    

public MyView(Context context) 
{
     super(context);
}




@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
   super.onDraw(canvas);

   int x = getWidth();
   int y = getHeight();
   int radius=200;
   int w=2*radius;
   int h=2*radius;
   boolean changed = mChanged;
   if (changed) {
       mChanged = false;
   }
   boolean seconds = mSeconds;
   if (seconds ) {
    mSeconds = false;
   }
  // radius = 200;
   Paint paint = new Paint();
   paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
   paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
   canvas.drawPaint(paint);
   // Use Color.parseColor to define HTML colors
   paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#b60f2e"));
   canvas.drawCircle(x /2, y / 2, radius, paint);
   paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#f6e1ff"));
   canvas.drawLine(x/2, y/2 + radius,x/2, y/2-15 + radius, paint);
   canvas.drawLine(x/2 , y/2 - radius,x/2 ,y/2 - radius+15, paint);
   canvas.drawLine(x/2 + radius, y/2 , x/2 + radius-15, y/2, paint);
   canvas.drawLine(x/2 - radius, y/2, x/2 - radius+15, y/2, paint);
   canvas.save();
   canvas.rotate(mHour / 12.0f * 360.0f, x, y);
   final Drawable hourHand = mHourHand;

   hourHand.draw(canvas);
   canvas.restore();


  }
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'add resources'?

Comment: you can also draw drawables on canvas from your resources

Comment: yes i want that hourhand and minutehand on my canvas from the drawable folder but i dont know how to do it.

Comment: Why you don't use AnalogClock view? You could extend it in your class and override certain methods.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AnalogClock.html

Comment: yup i know that but i want to buid it on my own

Comment: @A.S. can u help me out

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android programming - drawing analog clock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016368/android-programming-drawing-analog-clock)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example that might be interesting for you. 
http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/

Otherwise you can use drawable instead of bitmap.. Basically you should get reference to drawable

```
Drawable hand = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.minute_hand);
```

and draw it on canvas in onDraw callback of your custom view

```
hand.draw(canvas);
```

**p.s.** next time look for similar questions because there are already a lot of those available